# How to code progress circle with image and text inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using progress bar from this source:
https://github.com/kottenator/jquery-circle-progress

it works, but when i put an image and text on top, it appears only right away after load, but then it is moved to the right of the circle.
I need the picture and the text to be always in the middle - when page loads, prgress circle runs and after the run. I just simply played with positions (relative on parent element and absolute on img and text) but it is the same. Maybe anyone had the same issue?

my code (cdn you can find in the link above):

```
<div id="circle" style="position:relative"><img src"img/img.png" style="position:absolute"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>



<script>

  $('#circle').circleProgress({
    value: 0.75,
    size: 80,
    emptyFill: "#eee",
    fill: {
      gradient: ["red"],
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: We can surely help you if you'd provide us with your code.

Comment: @obscure I have added code. maybe any ideas?

Comment: Updating your question with a couple of screen shots showing the position of the text/image before and after they get moved might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your image and text outside your circle, and wrap it all with a relative positions element:

```
<style>
#loading-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.circle-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


</style>

<div id="loading-wrapper">
  <div class="circle-content">
    <img src"img/img.png">
  </div>
  <div id="circle" style="position:relative"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/dist/circle-progress.js"></script>
<script>

    $('#circle').circleProgress({
        value: 0.75,
        size: 80,
        emptyFill: "#eee",
        fill: {
          gradient: ["red"],
        }
    });
</script>
```

Looks like the library you link to does a bit of DOM manipulation, such as replacing the #circle with a canvas element. Better to be safe and keep your html separate from the circle so it doesn't inadvertently get removed or changed in any way.

Comment: You're awesome!

Comment: Glad I could help. Do me a favor and mark my answer as accepted if it was what you were looking for.